# basic javascript - taking the integer value out of a string

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables, integer

Well, though I searched for learning sources I could not find the exact thing I wanted. Please help to improve this post rather than down-voting so that all new learners can improve their knowledge.

lets assume there is a variable

```
var y = "number12";

var z ="";
```

1. how to make z=12 (how take only the integer value out of y string variable)
2. how to make z=number13 (adding one to "number"+12 )

Comment: Have a look for "regular expressions". Alternatively you could try to split a string of this pattern into the non-number part and the number part (starting at the end of the string, checking if this character is still 0-9, going backwards, repeat). Increment the number part and combine those two parts back to a string again.

Comment: Does the string always end in a number? Is the `number` text constant?

Comment: @Alex K. yes number is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the number with a RegEx and then use `parseInt` to convert the string `"12"` to the number `12`.

```js
var y = "number12";
var x = parseInt( y.match(/\d+/) );
alert(x)
```

Comment: what is the difference between x = parseInt(y.match(/[\d\.]*/));   and  var x = parseInt( y.match(/\d+/) );

Comment: The `\d` matches a single digit like `1` and `\d+` matches one or more digits like `12`. `\d*` would match zero or one digits.`[\d\.]*` doesn't appear to work. For mor info about regexes: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
var y = "number12";
x = parseInt(y.match(/[\d\.]*/));
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that: *@Alex K. yes number is a constant*

Simply:

```
var x = "number" + (+y.substr(6) + 1);
```

Comment: @ Alex K. can you expain what is the difference between x = parseInt(y.match(/[\d\.]*/)); and var x = parseInt( y.match(/\d+/) );

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736042/matthias)

```
var input = "number12";

// define a regular expression to match your pattern
var re = /(\D+)(\d+)/;

// execute the regexp to get an array of matches
var parsed = re.exec(input);  // ['number12', 'number', '12']

// parse an integer value of the number
parsed[2] = parseInt(parsed[2], 10); // '12' ==> 12

// increment the number
parsed[2] += 1; // 12 ==> 13

// rejoin the string
input = parsed[1] + parsed[2]; // 'number' + 13 ==> 'number13'
```